# I cannot align to center my table using HTML & CSS language

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I don't know what to put in the code of aligning the center of the table. I tried to insert the style="text-align: center;" in between the table tag but it did not work. Here is the code:

```
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Personal Finances</h1>
    <table border="2px";>
        <tr bgcolor="aqua">
            <th>Month:</th>
            <th>January</th>
            <th>February</th>
            <th>March</th>
            <th>April</th>
            <th>May</th>
            <th>June</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Income:</th>
            <td>P20 000</td>
            <td>P25 000</td>
            <td>P30 000</td>
            <td>P35 000</td>
            <td>P45 000</td>
            <td>P50 000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Expenses:</th>
            <td>P5000</td>
            <td>P6000</td>
            <td>P7000</td>
            <td>P8000</td>
            <td>P9000</td>
            <td>P10 000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Savings:</th>
            <td>P50 000</td>
            <td>P55 000</td>
            <td>P60 000</td>
            <td>P65 000</td>
            <td>P70 000</td>
            <td>P75 000</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

This is just a practice of making tables. I am currently new to programming, particularly HTML and CSS. Thank you for the help!

Comment: First of, stop using the inline `style` attribute (well, unless you're building for HTML-Email).  CSS should be in one place only and that's its respective tag or file.

Comment: Are you talking about vertical center? So centering the content of each cell?

Comment: He/She is talking about  centering the table in th page

Answer (score 1):

There is a property called `align="center"` which we can add to the table. Please find the below code. It'll work properly.

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Personal Finances</h1>
<table border="2px" ; align="center">
  <tr bgcolor="aqua">
    <th>Month:</th>
    <th>January</th>
    <th>February</th>
    <th>March</th>
    <th>April</th>
    <th>May</th>
    <th>June</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Income:</th>
    <td>P20 000</td>
    <td>P25 000</td>
    <td>P30 000</td>
    <td>P35 000</td>
    <td>P45 000</td>
    <td>P50 000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Expenses:</th>
    <td>P5000</td>
    <td>P6000</td>
    <td>P7000</td>
    <td>P8000</td>
    <td>P9000</td>
    <td>P10 000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Savings:</th>
    <td>P50 000</td>
    <td>P55 000</td>
    <td>P60 000</td>
    <td>P65 000</td>
    <td>P70 000</td>
    <td>P75 000</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class for table as `<table class="center">`,
and then add styles on separate style sheet

```
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: hahaha I also answered just the same just now

Comment: Oh, No. I got it from w3school ;)

Comment: Same I also got it from w3school!! hahahaha!! You must have searched same thing and copied code from first result!

Comment: or just use a single porperty: `margin: 0 auto`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` to do it. The code is as following-

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Personal Finances</h1>
<table border="2px" ; style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <tr bgcolor="aqua">
    <th>Month:</th>
    <th>January</th>
    <th>February</th>
    <th>March</th>
    <th>April</th>
    <th>May</th>
    <th>June</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Income:</th>
    <td>P20 000</td>
    <td>P25 000</td>
    <td>P30 000</td>
    <td>P35 000</td>
    <td>P45 000</td>
    <td>P50 000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Expenses:</th>
    <td>P5000</td>
    <td>P6000</td>
    <td>P7000</td>
    <td>P8000</td>
    <td>P9000</td>
    <td>P10 000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Savings:</th>
    <td>P50 000</td>
    <td>P55 000</td>
    <td>P60 000</td>
    <td>P65 000</td>
    <td>P70 000</td>
    <td>P75 000</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: or just use a single porperty: `margin: 0 auto`